# C static libraries do not recognize each other - why do I get "undefined reference to `function`"? (linker error)

Tags: c, static-libraries, linker-errors

So, I made one static library like this:

```
liba.h
-----
#ifndef LIBA_H
#define LIBA_H

void do_something();

#endif
```

and

```
liba.c
-----
#include "liba.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void do_something() {
    printf("liba\n");
}
```

And one more similar static library:

```
libb.h
-----
#ifndef LIBB_H
#define LIBB_H

void do_something_else();

#endif
```

and

```
libb.c
-----
#include "liba.h"
#include "libb.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void do_something_else() {
    do_something(); /* this is supposed to execute from liba */
    printf("libb\n");
}
```

And a simple main file:

```
main.c
-----
#include "liba.h"
#include "libb.h"

int main() {
    do_something_else();
}
```

The static libraries are compiled with:

```
gcc -c liba.c
gcc -c libb.c -I<path_to_liba.h>

ar rcs liba.a liba.o
ar rcs libb.a libb.o
```

And the main program is compiled with:

```
gcc main.c -I<path_to_liba.h> -I<path_to_libb.h>
    -L<path_to_liba.a> -L<path_to_libb.a> -la -lb
```

When I try to compile the main program I get a link error:

```
libb/libb.a(libb.o): In function `do_something_else':
libb.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `do_something'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

For some strange reason, when change my `main.c` file to this it works:

```
main.c
-----
#include "liba.h"
#include "libb.h"

int main() {
    do_something();
    do_something_else();
}
```

This not only compiles, but also gives the expected output:

```
Output:
    liba
    liba
    libb
```

How am I supposed to run `do_something_else` without calling `do_something` from the main file ? I'm obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: have you tried `gcc main.c <path_to_liba.a> <path_to_libb.a> -I<path_to_liba.h> -I<path_to_libb.h>`?

Comment: @ErikW I just did, unfortunately I get the exact same error

Comment: Try changing the order in which you specify both libraries on the command line. First b, which will satisfy the reference to `do_something_else` and introduce the (yet undefined) reference to `do_something`, which then can be satisfied by a.

Comment: @DanielJour This seemes to work! thanks a lot! if you post it as an answer I will accepted as solved!

Comment: Reversing the order (`-lb -la`) as suggested by @DanielJour will solve the problem. Also this will work without changing the order: `gcc main.c -I<path_to_liba.h> -I<path_to_libb.h>
    -L<path_to_liba.a> -L<path_to_libb.a> -Wl,--start-group -la -lb -Wl,--end-group` (`-Wl,--end-group` is optional). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quick solution

Change the order in which you specify the static libraries.

### Explanation

With static libraries the order in which you specify the libraries matters. The reason is that the linker will only include an object file from within a static library (remember, those are basically just archives of object files) if that object file resolves a previously unresolved symbol.

Taking your example and the order `liba.a libb.a`:

Compiling `main.c` gives an object file with an unresolved symbol `do_something_else`. Now the linker opens `liba.a`, looks at the symbols exported in the single object file `liba.o` contained within and finds no match for `do_something_else` (as only `do_something` is exported from `liba.o`). Thus, still needing to resolve `do_something_else`, the linker looks at the next library, `libb.a`, looks at the symbols exported from `libb.o`, finds `do_something_else` and thus adds `libb.o` to the object files which will be linked. `libb.o` contains an unresolved reference of the symbol `do_something`, thus the linker tries to resolve that. First, it looks in the library from which it took the object file `libb.o` to see if there's another object file which resolves the symbol. Then it tries to resolve the symbol with one of the next libraries / object files. Since there's neither another object file in the library `libb.a` nor further libraries / object files to look at, the linker fails with an unresolved symbol `do_something`.

When you use the order `libb.a liba.a`:

The unresolved symbol `do_something_else` from `main.o` is resolved by including `libb.o` from `libb.a`. This adds the unresolved symbol `do_something`, which then can be resolved by including `liba.o` from `liba.a`. Thus, linking succeeds.

### Rationale

Why not let the linker search all libraries for new unresolved symbols? I can only guess on this part here, but also provide a sensible use case:

Searching only once through the libraries in the order they were specified is simple. Both to implement as well as to understand. Also, consider this:

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
int calculate(int value);
int main() {
  printf("%d\n", calculate(42));
}
```

Now there's a library `libsuperfast.a` that contains (among other code) an implementation of `calculate` which depends on some platform specific stuff, and which is conditionally compiled only when on that platform. But you want to support other platforms, too. Thus you implement `calculate` by hand and put it into `libslowashell.a`. Linking like

```
$CC -o app main.o libsuperfast.a libslowashell.a
```

will include the fast code if its available and the slow code otherwise. Similar stuff is done for portability, e.g. in [gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/).

### Other solutions

- Unconditionally include whole static libraries, using `-Wl,--whole-archive`.
- Use [libtool](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/). Allows you to create both static and shared libraries without worrying about platform specifics too much. And handles dependencies between libraries for you.
- Resolve dependencies to `liba.a` manually when creating `libb.a`. To do this, first create an relocatable object file from the file(s) whose references to `liba.a` must be resolved, linking with `liba.a`, then create the library from that partially linked file (and possibly others):

  ```
  ld -r libb.o liba.a -o libb-partial.o
  ar rcs libb.a libb-partial.o # possibly others
  ```
- Use `-Wl,--start-group libb.a liba.a -Wl,--end-group`. This causes the linker to repeatedly search the libraries until either there are no more unresolved symbols or no more symbols can be resolved from the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

When linking with **static** libraries - position matters! In your case `libb` depends on `liba`, so, dependent library should be place after whoever uses it.

So, try this way:

```
gcc main.c -I<path_to_liba.h> -I<path_to_libb.h>
    -L<path_to_liba.a> -L<path_to_libb.a> -lb -la
```

Or even this way, if you don't want to care about the order:

```
gcc main.c -I<path_to_liba.h> -I<path_to_libb.h>
    -L<path_to_liba.a> -L<path_to_libb.a>
    -Wl,--whole-archive -la -lb -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

However, it this case whole libraries will be linked, even if it is not used at all.